# Jquery Tooltip on ModalpopupExtender

Tags: jquery, css, modalpopupextender

Last time I have an issue with the tooltip display position(solved).  This time, I notice something weird on the jquery tooltips.  It seems like the width of the tooltip is restricted by the modalpopupextender. The width of the tooltip can never get pass the right border of the modalpopup. Is there anything to do with the CSS I am using?

```
.tooltipx {
            display: none;
            font-family: Tahoma; 
            position: absolute;
            border: 2px solid #000000;
            background-color: #FFFFAA;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            color:  #000000;
            text-align: left;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by explicitly assigning specfic values to css width and maxwidth (optional?)(default is auto if not set) and now the tooltip's width will no longer limited by the modalpopup.